# nativescript sidekick cloud build fails

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

I can build successfully with `tns debug android` on local but when I try to do a clean cloud debug build with sidekick it fails with this weird error:

```
[20-02-06 00:49:17.869] (CLI) Webpack compilation complete.
[20-02-06 00:49:17.869] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: /mnt/storage/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.1/App/platforms/android/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
[20-02-06 00:49:17.869] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
[20-02-06 00:49:17.869] (CLI) cp: no such file or directory: /mnt/storage/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.1/App/app/App_Resources/Android/*
[20-02-06 00:49:19.401] (CLI) cp: no such file or directory: /mnt/storage/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.1/App/app/App_Resources/Android/*
[20-02-06 00:49:19.401] (CLI) bc_CGlurouIk2y9UbOVV5
[20-02-06 00:49:27.286] Build step completed.
[20-02-06 00:49:27.290] Build failed. Build failed. Reason is: 'Build failed with error code 2'. Additional information: [00:00:43.670] [WARN]  cp: no such file or directory: /mnt/storage/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.1/App/app/App_Resources/Android/*
[00:00:43.844] [ERROR] cp: no such file or directory: /mnt/storage/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.1/App/app/App_Resources/Android/*
'Build failed with error code 2'.
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: Try running `tns resources update` and also make sure you are having the requred Google services files https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#prerequisites

Comment: doesn't the fact that I can run `tns debug android` successfully mean that I already have those files?